# What forces to consider on a tracked vehicle?

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering

I'm aware that when calculating the power necessary to move a wheeled vehicle I should consider the rolling resistance, gradient resistance, air resistance and if it's a stopped vehicle the acceleration resistance, but what changes when dealing with tracked vehicles (see beloc)?

[image]

If I'm not wrong the *equation for wheeled vehicles*  goes like this (not taking into account a resting body accelerating):
$$
P = (c_r.m.a_g + m.a_g.sin(\alpha) + \frac{c_d.\rho.v^2.A}{2}).v
$$

where:
$c_r$ is the rolling coefficient; $m$ is the mass of the body; $a_g$ is the acceleration of gravity; $sin(\alpha)$ is the inclination; $c_d$ is the drag coefficient; $\rho$ is the density of the fluid; $v$ is the vehicles velocity; $A$ is the frontal area of the vehicle. (The friction coefficient of the gradient equation is omitted as the body has wheels so the rolling coefficient is taken into account)

Comment: Mass of the track? There are books about track technology.

Comment: Well, book recommendatins are always welcome, since I don't have a clue about this subject.

Comment: Don’t have a specific one to hand but now you can find one...

Answer (score 1):

As many as you want.

Look into [NATO mobility model](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235069513_Bekker%27s_Terramechanics_Model_for_Off-Road_Vehicle_Research).